# I'm trying to figure out how to clone text without cloning its element

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is when I click an element it clones into the 'b' tags.

Here is the html:

```
 <ol>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
    <li>x</li>
  </ol><b></b>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
        $("li").click(function(){$(this).clone().appendTo("b");});
```

What happens is i get a bullet point because there are 'li' elements around the text i want cloned. How do i get rid of them post clone or just clone the text since that seems like a better practice?

Here is the link on jfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m1yvLr86/

when you click 'this' items on the list, it returns bullet points but i just want the text!

Comment: Do you mean `this.textContent` ?

Comment: Something simple like [`$("b").append($(this).text());`](https://jsfiddle.net/m1yvLr86/1/) maybe …? You don’t need to actually “clone” the text in such an instance.

Comment: `$("li").click(function(){$("b").append($(this).text())});` As mentioned, you don't clone strings, just extract a copy of it and append

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It works, that could be a solution too...

Answer (score 0):

First get out the `b` element text, append the `li` text and add overwrite `b` text:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $('b').html($('b').html() + '<br>' + $(this).html());
});
```

Here is a live example: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1yvLr86/5/)**

Of course you can use space or new line or whatever instead `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("li").click(function(){

    text = '';
    var oldtext = $('b').text();
    var newtext = $(this).text();
    
    text = oldtext + newtext;
    

    $('b').text(text);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
    <li>x</li>
  </ol><b></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text function to retrieve the content of the li element without its tags:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    var text=$(this).text();
    // Do something with text (e.g. alert(text);
});
```

In my example, the text variable stores the clicked element text content: https://jsfiddle.net/ss3301qf/9/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, see code below which I've commented - applied a bit of CSS for clarity

```js
$("li").click(function() { /* capture the click */
  $("b").append( /* target element */
    $(this).text() /* get li text() */
  )
});
```

```css
li { cursor: pointer; }
b { padding: 12px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>y</li>
  <li>z</li>
  <li>x</li>
</ol><b></b>
```